# angularjs how to load partial

Tags: angularjs, templates, angularjs-directive, partial

I am trying to figure out how to correctly load partials in to dynamic template

something similar to this method [see link](https://coderwall.com/p/mgtrkg) -

I want to be able to have partial within universal partial - something like this www.onehungrymind.com/angular-dynamic-templates/

for example:

```
<main-partial>
    <!-- universal for view header -->

    <image-partial><!-- if this is image element, could be note --></image-partial>

    <!-- universal for view footer -->
</main-partial>

<main-partial>
    <!-- universal for view header -->

    <video-partial></video-partial>

    <!-- universal for view footer -->
<main-partial>
```

Universal template and + loading partials from files

**My plunker example** [link plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UXlqICBvqYZEtk1kN35n?p=preview)

```
...
```

Does anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: Have a look at this article: http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/

Comment: in my plunker example I used his example.
Now I am trying to load templates from html files - image.html, note.html and video.html

The other important thing is that I want to achieve <main-partial><video-partial><!-- content --></video-partial></main-partial> method which is described in https://coderwall.com/p/mgtrkg ... But I can not replicate it...